# Is "include file" in shtml the best method to keep non-database changing data

Tags: html, include, shtml

We have a website that uses `#include file` command to roll info into some web pages.  The authors can access the text files to update things like the occasional class or contact information for the department.

My question is this, I don't *see* anyone using this method and wonder if it is a good idea to keep using it.  If not, what method should I transition to instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with it, and I've done some similar things with PHP. If the people that make the changes are comfortable with how they do it and they can do what they need to, I think you should stick with it. There could be some retraining involved and/or a fair amount of work involved for changing the system.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ASP.NET then you could bundle that code into a nice little UserControl that will display all of the important information.

Other platforms should allow you to bundle the logic into a class object, and display it using that.

It really depends on the platform that you are using to deploy the application in. The include file could be your best solution if you are deploying in a more limited platform.

Comment: RZachary,
It is a very limited deployment. It is very bare-bones (i.e. one file per page sort of web 1.0 site).